# Problems with React Router Redux ("React.createElement: type is invalid" error)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I've got some problems setting up React-Router-Redux.
I'm just following the basic example on https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux#usage.

My App.jsx looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import Home from './containers/Home';
import About from './containers/About';
import store from './store';

const history = createHistory();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
          </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I save this, I get the following error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
>
> Check your code at App.js:25.

And line 25 is:
`<ConnectedRouter history={history}>`

Can someone help me out?

These are my dependencies:

```
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConnectedRouter` component available for `react-router-redux` version 5. Look at [this issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4694). As we can see from your dependencies, you are using `react-router-redux` version 4 currently.

So you should upgrade your `react-router-redux` package this way:

if you use `npm`:

```
npm install react-router-redux@next
```

or if you use `yarn`:

```
yarn add react-router-redux@next
```